# node.js JSON AJAX data not being read

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I am following a simple tutorial found here

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

My data:

```
[{"idQuestion":1,"content":"What is the difference between HTML and XML?"}, {"idQuestion":2,"content":"What is the module code of Advanced Programming?"}, {"idQuestion":3,"content":"What is the author of this websites first name?"}, {"idQuestion":4,"content":"What is the correct syntax to retrieve data from a Mongo Database?"}, {"idQuestion":5,"content":"Which one of these statements is false?"}]
```

Their data:

```
[ { "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "City" : "Berlin", "Country" : "Germany" }, { "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp", "City" : "Luleå", "Country" : "Sweden" }, { "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma", "City" : "México D.F.", "Country" : "Mexico" }, { "Name" : "Ernst Handel", "City" : "Graz", "Country" : "Austria" }, { "Name" : "FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A.", "City" : "Madrid", "Country" : "Spain" }, { "Name" : "Galería del gastrónomo", "City" : "Barcelona", "Country" : "Spain" }, { "Name" : "Island Trading", "City" : "Cowes", "Country" : "UK" }, { "Name" : "Königlich Essen", "City" : "Brandenburg", "Country" : "Germany" }, { "Name" : "Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars", "City" : "Vancouver", "Country" : "Canada" }, { "Name" : "Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti", "City" : "Bergamo", "Country" : "Italy" }, { "Name" : "North/South", "City" : "London", "Country" : "UK" }, { "Name" : "Paris spécialités", "City" : "Paris", "Country" : "France" }, { "Name" : "Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery", "City" : "Albuquerque", "Country" : "USA" }, { "Name" : "Simons bistro", "City" : "København", "Country" : "Denmark" }, { "Name" : "The Big Cheese", "City" : "Portland", "Country" : "USA" }, { "Name" : "Vaffeljernet", "City" : "Århus", "Country" : "Denmark" }, { "Name" : "Wolski Zajazd", "City" : "Warszawa", "Country" : "Poland" } ]
```

I have used this data in a Tomcat project so am sure it's in the correct format, however it isn't being read as looking as the network get request it doesn't download anything.

I have no idea why, is it the formatting?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Please show how you request the json

Comment: Thanks bud figured it out, needed to allow cross server requests by adding 

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");